# Is there any way to find commented data from python program

Tags: python

I would like to extract only commented data from python program.

```
def addlist():
    '''
    method to add all the number in a list
    :return:integer
    '''
    input_number = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    sum = reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, input_number, 10)
    print("sum is:", sum)
    return sum
```

I was trying some regex but could not do it successfully. I want to get

> 'method to add all the number in a list:return:integer'

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you can get it using `__doc__` method, or you can use a tool such as pydoc that will extract those strings as documentation, and then you can template the documentation for whatever you want to present it.

Comment: @Dan remove regex tag from the question as this question has been answered and it has nothing to do with regex.  tx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve it with `addList.__doc__`.